# Right click on sheet-tabs disabled in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, right-click

I used this vba code in the ThisWorkbook module to disable the right click menu in an Excel workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
   With Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=847)
      .Visible = False
   End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
   With Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=847)
      .Visible = True
   End With
End Sub
```

Works like a charm.
Problem is, I can't access the right click menu on tabs in ANY workbook now.
The second part of the code is supposed to turn it back on, I assumed? Yet it doesn't.

Even when I remove the code entirely, no workbook, not even a new one, has a menu when I click right on one of the tabs.

Is there a general vba codesnippet that "resets" excel maybe? Or a general "enable all menus" thing?

**REVISION:
This code posted here doesn't disable the rightclick menu, it removes the "delete" option from that specific menu.**

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior here. I got the context menus back after successfully ran `Enabled = True` for every single `Application.CommandBars` as @Kablam stated, but they are gone again after closing the workbook. So, I wonder if the problem could really be solved with few lines of VBA code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

omg

```
Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = True
```

-.-
Started googling different keywords after the last edit and BAM.

Comment: Ok, good for you and us all!
Now, mark it as the correct answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

Late again as usual, but tackled with the same problem today. Here's the solution to get your right-click functionality back:

```
Option Explicit
'
Sub tester()
    '
    Dim cBar As CommandBar
    '
    For Each cBar In CommandBars
        Debug.Print cBar.Name
        If (cBar.Type = msoBarTypePopup) Then cBar.Enabled = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This macro saved the day for me. Now I just need to work out what stole the right click function in the first place!

Comment: For the past few days I am not able to right click on sheet-tabs in Excel and select move or copy. The right click menu is not coming up. It looks like it could be a VBA issue as MS support person did help to fix this issue by adding some script in the VBA panel but now it's back after restarting the system.

How do you apply this? (sorry for my VBA illiteracy )

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the below also exist.  Some macro from work had them all disabled in my Excel.

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = True
Application.CommandBars("Row").Enabled = True
Application.CommandBars("Column").Enabled = True
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your contribution, but this doesn't really answer the question. You can find suggestions for crafting good answers one the help page [answer].